# Merge / Combine two php functions for Previous and Next Link with Thumbnail

Tags: php, functions

I will wrap two merged php funtions in one div container - so i have only one php function and one link to the next post, regardless if someone clicks on the thumb or the text part.

These are the two functions i use:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<nav><span class="button-nav">Previous Post<br /><span style="color: #666;font-size:10px;">%title</span></span></nav>' ); ?>
```

and:

```
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true); $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, 'thumbnail' ); echo $nextthumbnail; ?><?php previous_post_link( '%link', $prevThumbnail ); ?>
```

How can i merge the above two codes to one?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  If you are looking for assistance, we need a question to answer.  Happy to help but need to know with what.

Comment: I edit the question with "How can i merge the above two codes to one?" thx